# Ionic 2 on-tap disables scrolling on image

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am making an app that is a simple image gallery with clickable images. When I use on-tap I am unable to scroll if I start the scroll on the image. Is there a way to keep the on-tap functionality but allow scrolling?

**Update**: Found a workaround by using (click) instead of on-tap but I am still interested in the correct way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please answer your own question if you found a solution. Some code would be appreciated for other users.

Comment: I am still interested in the correct way to fix the problem instead of the workaround but I will post the fix as an answer.

Comment: Thank you. What you can do is to wait for another answer before accepting an answer, and maybe specifying in your question that you're still looking for an answer (people may not read comments)

Comment: Is there any solution to that? (click) has a delay of 300ms, so (click) is not a solution for us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround by using (click) instead of on-tap.